# Overlappint Texts with AlwaysVisibleControlExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, fixed, overlapping

I used AlwaysVisibleControlExtender to make a panel fixed at some position, now I have this fixed panel which has a text and there are multiple texts under this panel, now when I do scrolling, the texts under the panel is overlapped with the text in the panel.

How can I make the text under the panel not overlapped, so it stops before it reaches the text inside the panel.

here the code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <ajaxToolkit:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender ID="AlwaysVisibleControlExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Panel1"></ajaxToolkit:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderColor="Green" BorderStyle="Solid" style="position:fixed;z-index:1;">
        This text is inside the panel</asp:Panel>
    <p>
        This is the text outside the panel
    </p>
    <p>
        This is the text outside the panel
    </p>
    <p>
        This is the text outside the panel
    </p>
    <p>
        This is the text outside the panel
    </p>
    <p>
        This is the text outside the panel
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put All The
`<p> tag Text Inside The Panel`

Comment: no I don't want the texts to be inside the panel, I want them outside the panel